# Passing a file descriptor from `open_memstream` to `dup2`

Tags: c, unix, stream, posix

I am trying to redirect output from an `exec()`ed function into a buffer, so I though I would try and use `open_memstream` to handle the dynamic buffering

I put together this to test it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char* buffer;
    size_t buffer_len;
    FILE* stream = open_memstream(&buffer, &buffer_len);
    if(!stream) perror("Something went wrong with `open_memstream`!");
    fflush(stream);

    puts("Start");

    if(dup2(fileno(stream), STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) perror("Something went wrong!");

    puts("Internal");

    fclose(stream);

    FILE* f = fopen("out.txt", "w+");
    fputs(buffer, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

But running it gives me the error `bad file descriptor` on `dup2`, which shouldn't be the case since `open_memstream` doesn't return `NULL` which it is supposed to do on error.

Is there something about the implementation of `open_memstream` that makes it nonviable to manipulate its underlying descriptor? Or am I just being dumb and using a function wrong?

Cheers in advance for any help given, and if this *is* impossible to do with `open_memstream`, is there a way to handle it with `FILE*` instead of using fds directly?

Comment: "_There is no file descriptor associated with the file stream returned by these functions (i.e., `fileno(3)` will return an error if called on the returned stream)._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo ah - I always forget to read the `Notes` :p - ty!

Comment: A memstream doesn't use its `fd` in the same way, if at all. So, you can _not_ dup it--sorry.

Comment: Adding to what has been already said: mem_stream is a concept which relies purely within libc. Linux OS knows nothing about it, and can't do anything with it. `dup2` is a call which is implemented within Linux, though - so those two simply don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check return value (and subsequently `errno`) after *every* operation that can go wrong. Here, you are missing a check for `fileno(stream)` return value.

```c
FILE* stream = open_memstream(&buffer, &buffer_len);
if(!stream) perror("Failed to open_memstream");

int fd = fileno(stream);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Failed to get memstream fileno");
    exit(1);
}
```

When you add the above, your program will fail with message

```
Failed to get memstream fileno: Bad file descriptor
```

The reason for this failure is already explained in comments on the question.

Have look at `open` with the `O_TMPFILE` parameter, or at `memfd_create`, which is similar to `open_memstream` but returns a file descriptor.

These approaches force you to forgo the convenience of having `&buffer`, `&buffer_len`. But nothing is actually lost. One can use `lseek` to learn the tmp file size and then `mmap` to access it as a memory buffer, getting all the conveniences back.